# Proof that $\frac 1{10}$ has no finite binary float representation

Tags: binary, floating-point

I am supposed to prove that $\frac 1{10}$ is not representable as a finite binary float. I tried proving this via induction but that did not seem to work, now I am out of ideas. Thank you

Comment: https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: The only fractions that can be represented as finite binary fractions are those that have denominator as a power of $2$

Comment: Do you know how to derive $0.1_{10} = 0.00011001100110011\dots_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base-$b$ numeral with $k$ digits after the <s>decimal</s> radix point represents a fraction of the form $\frac{m}{b^k}$, where $m$ is an integer.  For example, in familiar base-ten:

$$0.04 = \frac{4}{10^2} = \frac{1}{25}$$
$$123.456 = \frac{123456}{10^3} = \frac{15432}{125}$$

The same logic applies to binary numerals ($b = 2$).  If the fraction $\frac{1}{10}$ had a finite decimal representation, there would exist integers $m$ and $k$ such that:

$$\frac{1}{10} = \frac{m}{2^k}$$

Or, equivalently:

$$2^k = 10 m$$
$$2^{k-1} = 5m$$

Which would require that some power of 2 be a multiple of 5.  But since 2 isn't divisible by 5, this is impossible.

---

Instead, you can only write $\frac{1}{10}$ as a repeating binary fraction.

$$0.1_{10} = 0.0\overline{0011}_2 = 0.00011001100110011..._2$$

Or round it off to some finite number of binary digits.

$$0.1_{10} \approx 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 = \frac{3602879701896397}{2^{55}} = \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{2^{55}\times5}$$

This is the value that your computer actually stores if you write `0.1` using standard [IEEE 754 double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  The rounding error is infinitesimal, but often confuses newbie programmers.  For example, in Python:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write it in the form $m/2^k$ since $10$ has a factor of $5$.